# $Lookup nested array element in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have two collects `students` and `classes`, and I want to query the all students with their free classes.

Mongo Playground at https://mongoplayground.net/p/WwON7lHbAvn

Collection `students`

```
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "John"
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "Nancy"
    }
  ]
```

Collection `classes`:

```
[
    {
      type: "free",
      "enrollment": [
        {
          studentID: 1,
          other: "other value"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      type: "common",
      "enrollment": [
        {
          studentID: 1,
          other: "other value"
        },
        {
          studentID: 2,
          other: "other value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

My Query:

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "classes",
      let: {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            type: "free",
            $expr: {
              "enrollment.studentID": "$$id"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "freeclasses"
    }
  }
])
```

But it gives me the error `FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.`

Also demonstrate at https://mongoplayground.net/p/WwON7lHbAvn

Many thanks for any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *FieldPath field names may not contain '.'.*

The error comes from `$expr: { "enrollment.studentID": "$$id" }`, this is invalid syntax for `$expr`, to fix this,

```
$expr: { $eq: ["$enrollment.studentID", "$$id"] }
```

But this just resolved your error, there is another issue the `enrollment` is an array and when we check any condition with field `enrollment.studentID` will return array of ids, so you can use `$in` instead of `$eq`,

Final solution is,

```
$expr: { $in: ["$$id", "$enrollment.studentID"] }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JfsA3QwogJM)